# Reload parent of iframe if no cookie?

Tags: cookies, refresh

I'm looking for a way to reload, from an iframe, it's parent page, but only once.

So basically I need to:

1. Check if a cookie exists
2. If not, write cookie and refresh parent page

Anyone know how to do it with PHP/JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to `create` and `read` cookies from `JavaScript`.

Check if what returns from `createCookie` function in `null` to determine that cookie was not set.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Read more about cookies [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Comment: I don't know much JavaScript. So instead of the return null; part, I can put my command, like parent.location.reload(); there?

Comment: Use code: var myCookie = readCookie("name-of-the-cookie"); if(myCookie == null) parent.location.reload();

Comment: And if I put that into a function, I can call the function from a body onLoad="" event?

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an idea what I should do.